# Querying 6 tables unable to echo info from master table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to query 6 separate tables in my mysql database, the structures are as follows;

```
item
itemitemid | item | description | brand | date | time | path |

actor
actoractorid | name | actorthumb | bio |

brand
brandbrandid | brandname | description | image |

movie
moviemovieid | title | genre | year | moviethumb | synopsis|

users
userid | name | surname | email | password |

request
requestid | userid | itemid | brandid | movieid | actorid | content | requestdate |
```

Using the following query I can display for example where the requestid=1 I can see the movie in the request, the actor in the movie, the item of clothing they were wearing and its brand.

```
$requestid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['requestid']);
        $query = "select r.requestid, m.*, a.*, i.*, b.* 
        FROM request r INNER JOIN movie m ON m.movieid = r.movieid 
        INNER JOIN actor a ON a.actorid = r.actorid 
        INNER JOIN item i ON i.itemid = r.itemid 
        INNER JOIN brand b ON b.brandid = r.brandid 
        WHERE r.requestid = $requestid";
```

However when I try to echo out "content" and "request date" from the request table. The data simply doesn't appear. I also cannot get the info from the user table, e.g the user logging the request by by adding the following join;
$query = "select r.requestid, m.*, a.*, i.*, b.*, u.*
INNER JOIN users u ON u.userid = r.userid

Please advise?

Comment: ah just replaced the select r.requestid with select r.* and it seems to work, simple as that! How do I add the users table to the query too so I can see who logged the request?

Answer (score 1):

You aren't `SELECT`ing those fields. Right now, you're only `SELECT`ing `r.requestid` from the `requests` table. You need to add references to every field you want to echo.

As far as the User join, you just seem to be joining on the wrong field. You need to join on `u.userid = r.userid`. Right now, you're joining on `u.itemid` which doesn't exist. You'll also need to change your `SELECT` statement to report the fields you want (e.g. `SELECT ... , u.name, u.email`).

As an aside, you should avoid `SELECT`ing `table.*` where possible. This can break things when you add a field to a table but don't account for that when processing the results of a query. You should try to be explicit as possible, and `SELECT` only the fields you want to use - e.g. `SELECT users.name, users.email` rather than doing `SELECT users.*`.

Comment: @Martin Just change `SELECT r.requestid ...` to `SELECT r.requestid, r.content, r.requestdate ...`

Comment: Thanks agent that works, so does r.* how do I link the users table to this query so so I can display who logged the request?

Comment: @Martin I've updated my post. I think there are two problems: You're `JOIN`ing on the wrong field, and you're not `SELECT`ing the fields from the users table that you want to output.

Comment: @Martin From the query listed in that error, the problem is that you haven't defined `u` to anything (i.e. `users u` sets up an alias for `u` to point to `users`) and that's the wrong JOIN syntax regardless. Try changing that join to `INNER JOIN users u ON u.userid = r.userid`. Given the nature of your issues, I think you need to brush up on our SQL syntax a bit before continuing on. You seem to be missing some fairly basic stuff.

Comment: Apologies agent I have corrected the original post, in theory I should be able to use select u.* INNER JOIN user u ON u.userid = r.userid however this doesnt work when I load the page it's empty of all data when I add the users table part?

Comment: @AgentConundrum let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2592/discussion-between-martin-dye-and-agentconundrum)